# How to keep user-uploaded files when using github actions

Tags: laravel, git, github, github-actions

Questions is rather simple, and i am surprised that i could not find an answer. Maybe i just do not know what to ask. Here is the thing, i am using a Laravel app that serves as some sort of cloud-storage/file-system, and i am using github actions to deploy my latest code. I do not have access to git repo at the moment, but yml file is pretty simple, use actions checkout v2, then run some commands that i need, and voila, latest code is up. The only issue is, when that happens, everything gets deleted, including my storage folder, which is by convention used as a default upload location. So, is there some command that i should run so i just pull latest changes and not delete everything, or do i move storage folder outside of repo scope?

p.s i am self-hosted

Comment: I think the typical approach to persisting data across deployments is to do like you said;  move the storage directory outside of your project and symlink to it. I know Laravel Envoyer uses that approach.

Comment: I'm not sure why your storage folder would be getting deleted though... That's not the default Laravel behaviour. I can see mismatched resources if you're storing a reference to them in the DB; local DB won't match production DB for that, etc, but that's a different issue. I agree that an external source, like AWS S3, etc would fit your needs.

Comment: well, when checkout starts, it deletes everything thats inside project folder, i do not know why, its weird behavior, i would expect it to do a pull request, not explicitly do rm -rf, but i guess i can move storage folder elsewhere. Oh i also forgot to mention i am self hosted, so i do not really need S3 or something similar

Comment: @DigitalDrifter thanks for suggestion, i guess i will do that